# InstallShield - setting the SQL Server connection string for Entity Framework at time of install

Tags: sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, installshield

Has anyone out there been able to accomplish this task?  InstallShield prompts the user to connect to their local / networked sql server database and collects all that information (server name, catalog, username, password, etc.).

I need to plug this information into a connection string for entity framework, not replacing attribute values, but actually doing a text replace within the attribute value.  I.E. replace "MyServer" with the server name they connect to.

In working with InstallShield I do not see a way to take those connection settings and "plug them in" to the EF connection string.  Anyone had success with this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer for this is to use the InstallShield feature "Text File Changes" found under the "System Configuration" section.  This feature allows you to take the user-defined connection properties for sql server and replace text in the config file.

For example, my base config file contains the text "Server=MyServerName;" in the connection string.  InstallShield finds this text and replaces it with "Server=[IS_SQLSERVER_SERVER];" which comes from the prompt where the user connects to their sql server instance.

For some reason the "XML File Changes" does not allow for text replacement and that's where I was getting off track.